# Does "Rename Symbol" work across files when editing JavaScript?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does the "Rename Symbol" feature work across files, when editing JavaScript? Currently it's only working within the current file being edited. I seem to recall it working across files, though. It would open all the files that it had made changes to. It's no longer doing that, though.

Am I remembering incorrectly or does it work this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The feature `Rename Symbol` only works for the current file. But there is another feature, which fits your description: `Replace in Files` (Menu Bar: `Edit` > `Replace in Files`).

From [Visual Studio Code User Guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-across-files):

> You can also Search and Replace across files. Expand the Search widget
>   to display the Replace text box.
>
> When you type text into the Replace text box, you will see a diff
>   display of the pending changes. You can replace across all files from
>   the Replace text box, replace all in one file or replace a single
>   change.

For a quick use you can select a word in your source and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

Comment: I don't believe it's true that "Rename Symbol" only works on the current file, as described here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_rename-symbol

Comment: Although the docs claim that Rename Symbol renames across files, I tried to do that with a python project and that feature couldn't find all the occurrences of the selected symbol like the Replace in Files feature.

Comment: It works in typescript but from my experience in plain javascript it doesn't work but it makes sense because vanilla javascript doesn't really have a way of knowing what files are related or included in each other. You could be relying on html files not open in the editor to include the js files or could have to very similar to separate js files with the same names and you wouldn't want rename to affect the other one. (A reason why I favor long descriptive names). The global find & replace is as good as I can do but you have to be careful. I usually evaluate the replacements 1 by 1.